# Implement JSON deserialization at the type level

Tags: json, typescript, serialization

I want to implement json serialization and deserialization at the type level of typescript.

I found an implementation of deserialization on [github](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/json-parser-in-typescript-very-bad-idea-please-dont-use).

How can I implement serialization?

Comment: Maybe what you need are the `class-validator` and `class-transformer` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented it myself:

```js
// https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/2835
type UnionToIntersection<T> = (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends (x: infer U) => any ? U : never
type LastUnion<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never> extends (x: infer L) => any ? L : never
export type UnionToTuple<T, Last = LastUnion<T>> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, Last>>, Last]

type obj2json<keys, T> = keys extends []
    ? ''
    : keys extends [infer a]
    ? a extends string
        ? a extends keyof T
            ? `"${a}":${stringify<T[a]>}`
            : never
        : never
    : keys extends [infer a, ...infer as]
    ? a extends string
        ? a extends keyof T
            ? `"${a}":${stringify<T[a]>},${obj2json<as, T>}`
            : never
        : never
    : never
type arr2json<items> = items extends []
    ? ''
    : items extends [infer a]
    ? `${stringify<a>}`
    : items extends [infer a, ...infer as]
    ? `${stringify<a>},${arr2json<as>}`
    : never
type stringify<T> = T extends object
    ? T extends Array<unknown>
        ? `[${arr2json<T>}]`
        : UnionToTuple<keyof T> extends infer keys
        ? `{${obj2json<keys, T>}}`
        : never
    : T extends string
    ? `"${T}"`
    : T extends number
    ? `${T}`
    : T extends boolean
    ? `${T}`
    : never

type x1 = stringify<{ a: '1'; b: 2; c: { a: 1 } }>
type x2 = stringify<{ a: [1, 2, 3] }>
type x3 = stringify<{ a: [1, 2, { a: 1; b: 2; c: [1, true] }] }>
```

This is a rough implementation without recursive optimization. When there are too many json levels, errors may occur: `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`

But this is enough for me, any optimization schemes please suggest in the comments.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthIBPGAUwFp9wBDAGyaoDtkq4zLb7nWHLsFRw4mYQCYAHAGYArAFgAUBWqgAqm1SE2AFUIBJNpCoAnOFXyQdbADx6AfKAC8oABR7QVAB6m2ACZwoAxs5KAA-B4+CKB6AJSuzqHhsWxUAG7mib7+QdGxqGwAZuaaiS7JYZGaoGmZ5ipqVKAAMgxwkFq2Ds5u3boGxqYWVja6Dt5+7PkpNe4xcRVVqaDpWWbOuTPBC4UlZa3LIdVRrXVrDWYqvjCEZpCgzZrag4R6mDCsDgA0bR2PNztToDexOPqgADaegAulM8sFIetzHCopC4bFIbhsaCDB8vlQ7ABRHz4JiYAKEvR-YGQRyOGkAmEqJq8UCEbAAK0knLgEwA1lRyHA-k5XKBBcL4TsoczlKAFTUAORKlSKi6S4LbQKIoqlMwhOXqqIMaU60CdMxFZBq9WKk1m-KSwjFOK2u12qIAAwARAASADeDAAvj6EIHLdbUMVyA5IQwYY5g173R7FfUNqn1RnGvL0xKhVrpubIXqygw-tjcGWDR0jfaQo7gpGOFmG6btU6hS63Xm0w3fYGQ2GI5ArRxo7G9PHE8GfoGOdzeRMOqKkym+-2Lsjrpvs5dM5uc7vngwzGYeXz7OgqMQ4BCb3em7LU1EVanCqYn53dQda-WFW9UdxzQGM7AYdcP1AR8iwRKEaxCStsQQutX1AL1gKjMCILnIdz0vFd72TKCd1ZdQW1AqcIS8H92S5MY0Jo4t8gAQXPBhY0wNh+TYQgAHc2EcNtAPQyE8IvZcwSTGEN37WJcXeT5vmdV0xVohDNWEmovQDBcuQI+xNTXYNiL3fNSKPOJnwotDBwDPRQ1k-MmLgthMGIbBc2NdDAwcpyFViFyZWwQhCFYUJbN80z9wssiWh8ABGcUKMnOwAxCWIlQSpUAG5QGwWJJDy-BYnShhYiS4NQGDITVDZHxJGSscsNjMrMQSv5JD+WQ4RquLQB8WQmpA1K2qhDrQC60AxoSvKCsm4r2r+McJF63raqAA)

Comment: Oh, wow. What's the use case for this? 

Comment: Originally I wanted to construct a new type system and intended to use json to represent it, so I naturally thought that serialization and deserialization were needed, but I have not used serialization so far. Maybe this idea is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "type level serialization", but you could just wrap these in type checked functions. `stringify` will work fine on a type checked function since TypeScript can type-check the input:

```js
function serialize(data: SomeInterface): string {
  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Deserialization is more tricky, as the input `string` might contain anything. I don't think you can solve this compile-time. So, in this case if you need more guarantees you'll need to do run-time validation:

```js
function deserialize(input: string): SomeInterface {
  const data = JSON.parse(input);

  // Do some validation

  return data;
}
```

If you're **absolutelly sure** that the input string complies with the interface then you can just cast:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(input) as SomeInterface;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want is the operation on the type level. I have implemented it. You can refer to my answer and pay attention to the types of `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`.
"Type-level" refers to programming the type, similar to a function call, except that the parameters are all types instead of values, and the result of the call is also a type instead of a value. A new type is generated through one or more types. This is the type level Programming.
For me, this can help me better describe the type constraints of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what means "at the type level", but if it means having classes instances in place of values (such as `Date` instances or your own class instances), then you may be interested in `@badcafe/jsonizer` : https://badcafe.github.io/jsonizer/#/